# hover and changing the opacity of a div and an element

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I am creating a box in html that contains a title, a background image, and a ghost div on top of it that appears on hover with a link.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class = "box-wrapper">
  <div class = "ghost-box">
    <a class = "link-button"></a>
  </div>
  <div class = "content-box">
    <h3 class = "title">Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.box-wrapper {display:inline-block;}
.ghost-box {
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(1, 81, 161, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.ghost-box:hover {opacity:1;}
.content-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-image:url('example.jpg');
}
.title {
  opacity:1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

My conundrum is, the hover transition on the ghost div works great, but I would also like to affect the "title" element as well. I don't want to decrease the opacity of the "content-box" because I want the background image to still show through the ghost div, but I want the title to change it's opacity to 0. I've tried several combinations of things from:

```
.content-box:hover:first-child {opacity:0;}
```

to:

```
.box-wrapper:hover:last-child {opcaity:0;}
```

but nothing seems to be working. Any advice? I hope I made things clear enough.

Comment: The whole point is to fade the content, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you move the hover to the container element you can do this.

```
.box-wrapper:hover .ghost-box {
  opacity: 1
}
.box-wrapper:hover .title {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Or you can use the CSS general sibling selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: Using the wrapper to check for `:hover` is definitely a better way to go.

Comment: @chinoto the reason why I added both though is that the wrapper could contain other HTML or the ghost box might not entirely fill the wrapper.

Comment: Yep, which is exactly why it's the better way to go :)

Comment: @CKH4 that works! Thanks so much. The only thing is that breaks certain a links in the ghost div, they won't click. Seems to be arbitrary. Not sure why

Comment: In case it's a z-index issue you can use `pointer-events: none` on the content-box

Comment: @James Hamann it would be really helpful if you made a jsfiddle or codepen demonstrating the issue so I can try to diagnose it.

Comment: @CKH4 I created a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/eyyq138u/12/) but can't recreat the problem. Seems like it's something to do with bootstrap maybe. I'll have to talk to the original developers of the site, as I'l jumping in late. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Set the background-image on `.box-wrapper.`
Option 2: Set opacity on the contents of `.content-box` using `.content-box>*`
Option 2: Wrap the contents of `.content-box` with another div (`.content-box-fader`?) that you apply the fade effect to.